# Error initializing WebDriver Chrome causing failure to wait for extension background to load

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, leanft

I am using Selenium C# + LeanFT to automate a web application.  I sometimes get this error in Visual Studio, and I do not know why.  Can someone shed light on how I might handle this:

> Error initializing WebDriver Chrome -> unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://hpoiplhbnkgnpjkkilfahkkcimachkkj/Agent/Ext/bg-loader.html
>   from timeout
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)Automation.Test.Framework.Models.Exceptions.AtGenericException: Error initializing WebDriver Chrome ---> System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://hpoiplhbnkgnpjkkilfahkkcimachkkj/Agent/Ext/bg-loader.html
>   from timeout
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
>      at Automation.Test.Framework.Decorators.ChromeDriverDecorator..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeDriverOptions options)
>      at Automation.Test.Framework.Decorators.AtWebDriver.get_GetDriver()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Automation.Test.Framework.Decorators.AtWebDriver.get_GetDriver()
>      at Symphony.AcceptanceTests.Hooks.TestHook.RegisterAndInitializeWebDriver() in C:\Users\amaddox\Desktop\H\Symphony.AcceptanceTests\Symphony.AcceptanceTests\Hooks\TestHook.cs:line 161
>      at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType)
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioStart(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
>      at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnScenarioStart(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
>      at Symphony.AcceptanceTests.Epics.CC_TransitionFiles.Feature._9317_TransitionFilesUploadFeature.ScenarioSetup(ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
>      at Symphony.AcceptanceTests.Epics.CC_TransitionFiles.Feature._9317_TransitionFilesUploadFeature.PBIXXXXBulkUploadStructuredDocs() in C:\Users\amaddox\Desktop\H\Symphony.AcceptanceTests\Symphony.AcceptanceTests\Epics\CC - Transition Files\Feature\9317_TransitionFilesUpload.feature:line 31
>      at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
>      at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
>      at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestAssemblyExecutor.ExecuteTestNodeTask(TestNode testNode, ITaskExecutor task, TraceEventType eventType)

Comment: A plugin with high load time may be?

Comment: @TarunLalwani What do you mean?  Is there a way to resolve?

Comment: Not sure, but can you check if the plugin is slow and causing the issue or is it something else?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Do you have a workaround now?